# touch events problem

Tags: iphone

I found a very strange problem while handling touch events. The idea of an app is that i have an ImageView which contains a circle with text, that the user can rotate.
I've implemented a custom UIScrollView subclass to contain circle image. There i implemented methods touchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchesEnded in order to rotate my circle when user drags it left or right. Everything works fine, but when you try to drag it with one finger very fast from one side to another and in opposite direction, methods touchesBegan and touchesEnded are called different number of times. For example touchesBegan was called 1 time and touchesEnded 2 - 3 times. How can it be?

```
   - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    if([[event touchesForView:self] count]==1){

            touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
            previousTouchPoint = touchPoint;
            angle = 0;
            if (((touchPoint.x > 160)&&(touchPoint.y < 210))||((touchPoint.x < 160)&&(touchPoint.y > 210))) {
                leftRotation = YES;
            }
            else {
                leftRotation = NO;
            }

            currentMoveAngle = 0;
        }
    }

    - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event{
        if([[event touchesForView:self] count] == 1){
                CGPoint newPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
                CGPoint origin;
                if (self.tag == 2) {
                    origin = CGPointMake(self.bounds.origin.x+self.bounds.size.width*0.5, 215);
                }
                else {
                    origin = CGPointMake(self.bounds.origin.x+self.bounds.size.width*0.5, 215);
                }
                previousTouchPoint.x -= origin.x;
                previousTouchPoint.y -= origin.y;
                CGPoint second = newPoint;
                second.x -= origin.x;
                second.y -= origin.y;
                CGFloat rotationAngle = [self rotationFromFirstPoint:previousTouchPoint toSecondPoint:second];

                previousTouchPoint = newPoint;
                [self rotateContentToAngle:rotationAngle animated:NO];
                currentMoveAngle += rotationAngle; 
            }

    }

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event{
    if ([[event touchesForView:self] count] == 1){
        rotating = YES;
            CGFloat rotationAngle;
            CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(self.bounds.origin.x+self.bounds.size.width*0.5, 215);
            CGPoint lastPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
            CGPoint touchP = touchPoint;
            if ((touchP.x != lastPoint.x)||(touchP.y != lastPoint.y)) {
                touchP.x -= origin.x;
                touchP.y -= origin.y;
                lastPoint.x -= origin.x;
                lastPoint.y -= origin.y;

                if (fabs(currentMoveAngle)>M_PI/6) {
                     NSInteger index = (int)trunc(currentMoveAngle/(M_PI/3));
                     currentMoveAngle-=(M_PI/3)*index;
                    NSLog(@"rotation index: %i",index);
                 }

                if (leftRotation) {
                    rotationAngle = M_PI/3;
                    rotationAngle-=currentMoveAngle;
                }
                else {
                    rotationAngle = (-1)*M_PI/3;
                    rotationAngle-=currentMoveAngle;
                }

                [self rotateContentToAngle:rotationAngle animated:YES];
            }   
        }
}
```

Comment: Is multipleTouchEnabled?

Comment: hm, i'll chek that, but the thing is that i'm cheking number of touch points: if([[event touchesForView:self] count] == 1). Probably this somehow doesn't really work

Comment: Nope, disabling multiple touches doesn't solve the problem(

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you are using a `UIView` instead of a `UIScrollView`?

Comment: I can't use UIView here, because my circle image is bigger than the scrollView frame..

Answer (score 0):

UIScrollView handle touch event very badly.... may be it is happening because of dragging of scrollView.

try this

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    if (!self.dragging){   
   if([[event touchesForView:self] count]==1){

        touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
        previousTouchPoint = touchPoint;
        angle = 0;
        if (((touchPoint.x > 160)&&(touchPoint.y < 210))||((touchPoint.x < 160)&&(touchPoint.y > 210))) {
            leftRotation = YES;
        }
        else {
            leftRotation = NO;
        }

        currentMoveAngle = 0;
    }
}
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event{
  if (!self.dragging){      
  if([[event touchesForView:self] count] == 1){
            CGPoint newPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
            CGPoint origin;
            if (self.tag == 2) {
                origin = CGPointMake(self.bounds.origin.x+self.bounds.size.width*0.5, 215);
            }
            else {
                origin = CGPointMake(self.bounds.origin.x+self.bounds.size.width*0.5, 215);
            }
            previousTouchPoint.x -= origin.x;
            previousTouchPoint.y -= origin.y;
            CGPoint second = newPoint;
            second.x -= origin.x;
            second.y -= origin.y;
            CGFloat rotationAngle = [self rotationFromFirstPoint:previousTouchPoint toSecondPoint:second];

            previousTouchPoint = newPoint;
            [self rotateContentToAngle:rotationAngle animated:NO];
            currentMoveAngle += rotationAngle; 
        }

}
}

 - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event{
   if (!self.dragging){    
   if ([[event touchesForView:self] count] == 1){
    rotating = YES;
        CGFloat rotationAngle;
        CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(self.bounds.origin.x+self.bounds.size.width*0.5, 215);
        CGPoint lastPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
        CGPoint touchP = touchPoint;
        if ((touchP.x != lastPoint.x)||(touchP.y != lastPoint.y)) {
            touchP.x -= origin.x;
            touchP.y -= origin.y;
            lastPoint.x -= origin.x;
            lastPoint.y -= origin.y;

            if (fabs(currentMoveAngle)>M_PI/6) {
                 NSInteger index = (int)trunc(currentMoveAngle/(M_PI/3));
                 currentMoveAngle-=(M_PI/3)*index;
                NSLog(@"rotation index: %i",index);
             }

            if (leftRotation) {
                rotationAngle = M_PI/3;
                rotationAngle-=currentMoveAngle;
            }
            else {
                rotationAngle = (-1)*M_PI/3;
                rotationAngle-=currentMoveAngle;
            }

            [self rotateContentToAngle:rotationAngle animated:YES];
        }   
      }       }
      }


or make scrollingEnabled property NO.
```

Comment: well, the property scrollingEnabled was set to NO, and i already tried if (!self.dragging) with no effect..Anyway, thanks for the answer.